# aggregate data in irregular groups in r (any better title?)

Tags: r, aggregate, subset

I have a data frame like this:

```
ship_schedule<-c(1,0,1,0,1,0,0,
             1,0,0,1,0,1,0,
             0,1,0,1,0,1,0,
             0,1,0,0,1,1,0,
             1,0,0,1,0,1,0,
             1,0,1,0,1,1,0,
             0,1,0,1,1,1,0,
             1,0,1,1,0,1,0,
             1,0,1,1,1,1,0,
             0,1,1,1,1,1,0,
             0,1,1,1,1,1,1,
             1,0,1,1,1,1,1,
             1,1,1,1,1,1,0,
             1,1,1,1,1,1,1)

store <- rep(1:2, each=7*14*2)
type <- rep(c("a", "b"), each=7*14, times=2)
template <- rep(1:14, each=7, times=4) # I have 14 schedules and each one associated with 7 days
schedule <- rep(ship_schedule, times=4)
day <- rep(1:7, times=2*14*2)
demand<-sample(1:2,392,replace=T)
data <- data.frame(store, type, template, schedule, demand)
```

[image]

All I want to do is, for instance:

If a schedule is 
1
0
1
0
1
0
0(template 1) 
 the 1st shipment on Monday is the sum demand of Tuesday and Wednesday. We can think that the ending inventory on Wed's night is 0.

2nd shipment on Wednesday is sum of demand of Thursday and Friday.

3rd one on Friday is sum of demand Saturday and Sunday and this Monday.(Monday here because the demand is average value, so this Monday's demand is same as next Monday's demand ).

and if the template is like  0,1,0,1,0,1,0,  the ship on Sat is the sum demand of Sun,Mon and Tue.

The **tough** thing here is that the calculation of the demand on the ship at days like Fri SAT and Sun (which requires the sum of demand on Mon or Tue).

**The algorithm is something like calculating the distance between two 1's.**  And all the calculation should apply for the same store and same type.

And last I want add a column to store the value correspond to the 0/1 in the schedule column.

Since the the 0,1 in the ship_schedule is randomly distributed(fixed), it might be **not good** to use something like:

```
if (schedule [i]==1 & schedule [i+1]==1){
    value[i] <- testdemand[i+1]
    value[i+1] <- testdemand[i+2]
}
```

I would like define  14 function for each template and call the subset of data, but it seems too costly.
Does anybody knows any function or method that I should try?

Comment: I didn't understand your description of "1010100" at all. Does each number correspond to a day? Starting with something?

Comment: @MrFlick yes , it is how template 1 looks like in the data. There are 7 days and each day's schedule is either 0 or 1.

Comment: But that still doesn't explain any thing, or what it has to do with ships. How does "1010100" == "the shipment of the 1st ship is the sum demand of Tuesday and Wednesday" Tues/Wed are consecutive. Are they the last two zeros? Does your template start with Tuesday? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: This question really needs a bit of work.  Please assume we know nothing about your content area.  I see no days of the week in the data.  I'm confused what you want.  Also displaying the output you desire may help.  Otherwise this question may be closed as it's too difficult to decipher what you're after.

Comment: @MrFlick the 1st shipment on Monday is the to satisfy the demand on Tue and Wed. It is designed like this. Yes the template can start with Tuesday. My thinking is to calculate the index gap between two 1s and sum the demand to the 1st 1.

Comment: What demands should be summed when a shipment is -e.g.- on Sunday? Could you provide the exact output you want for these shown sample data?

Comment: @alexis_laz if there is a shop on Sunday, eg, 0110011 the sum should be the demand on Mon and Tue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure I understood exactly but here's an attempt, anyway, that could be helpful:

```
set.seed(101) ##before copy-pasting your code
```

First we could define a function that finds 1's and their immediate consecutive 1's and does the main calculations (at least that's what I understood from the question):

```
ff <- function(sched, dem)                                          
{
   inds <- which(as.logical(sched))
   sched2 <- rep(sched, 2)
   dem2 <- rep(dem, 2)
   res <- sapply(inds, 
            function(z) sum(dem2[(z + 1) : (which.max(tail(sched2, -z)) + z)]))
   ret <- numeric(7)
   ret[inds] <- res
   return(ret)
}
##test with the sample output shown
ff(c(1,0,1,0,1,0,0), c(1,2,2,1,1,2,1))
#[1] 4 0 2 0 4 0 0
ff(c(1,0,0,1,0,1,0), c(1,2,1,1,1,1,2))
#[1] 4 0 0 2 0 3 0
```

Then split data (by store, type and template) and apply "ff":

```
spl_data = split(data, 
                 interaction(data$store, data$type, data$template, drop = T))
new_data = do.call(rbind, lapply(spl_data, 
                                 function(x) {
                                   x$sum_dem = ff(x$schedule, x$demand)
                                   return(x)
                                 }))

rbind.data.frame(head(new_data, 7), "...", tail(new_data, 7))
#           store type template schedule demand sum_dem
#1.a.1.1        1    a        1        1      1       3
#1.a.1.2        1    a        1        0      1       0
#1.a.1.3        1    a        1        1      2       3
#1.a.1.4        1    a        1        0      2       0
#1.a.1.5        1    a        1        1      1       4
#1.a.1.6        1    a        1        0      1       0
#1.a.1.7        1    a        1        0      2       0
#8            ... <NA>      ...      ...    ...     ...
#2.b.14.386     2    b       14        1      2       2
#2.b.14.387     2    b       14        1      2       1
#2.b.14.388     2    b       14        1      1       1
#2.b.14.389     2    b       14        1      1       2
#2.b.14.390     2    b       14        1      2       1
#2.b.14.391     2    b       14        1      1       1
#2.b.14.392     2    b       14        1      1       2
#Warning message:
#In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "...") :
#  invalid factor level, NA generated
```